# List re-formatting in python

Tags: python, list, formatting

I have a list like this:

```
my_list = ['a,b,c']
```

Then I wanna reformat the list to

```
new_list = ["a","b","c"]
```

Can someone give a hand, I'm a newbie in Python. Thanks!

Comment: `new_list = my_list[0].split(",")` ... I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
my_list = ['a,b,c']
new_list = my_list[0].split(',')
print(new_list)
```

Output:-

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the first list holds only 1 item which is a string.

So, you can use `split()` method to split the string into an array as followings:

```
my_list = ['a,b,c']

new_list = my_list[0].split(",")

##                ^^^ This is to get the first item since the array has only 1 item
```

Comment: @Pygirl I know it's already been answered in the comment but I wanted to explain why OP needs to use `[0]` selector since OP said `I'm a newbie` and seems like confused about `'a,b,c'` being a `list` rather than a `string`.